# How to connect to a LAN with Proxy Settings

Tags: macos, networking, mac, proxy

I'm new to OS X and I want to connect my Macintosh through a LAN with wired connection using proxy settings and not using the WiFi connection.

How do I connect it to the LAN and use the internet?

Comment: Also if your are referring to a Macintosh Computer please specify what model it is, and if you know, what operating system version it is running?

Comment: What is providing the connection through the wired network?  A router? A modem?  More info needed.

Comment: MAC is Apple Macintosh compute and I am connection via Ethernet cable

Comment: Well, it's obvious that your LAN connection uses an Ethernet cable. We need more info, please. Why can't you just plug it in?

Comment: I have no idea to where I can set proxy for net connection on MAC OSX. When I connecting the cable in it

Comment: So? Plug in your ethernet cable, set up the ethernet adapter you are good to go. See the docs at https://help.apple.com/machelp/mac/10.7/help/index.html#mh11939%27

Comment: Please post any updated info/things you tried into your original post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You take your Ethernet cable …

[image: Ethernet cable]

… and plug it into the Ethernet port.

[image: Ethernet port]

Then go to **<kbd>Apple</kbd> ➮ System Preferences ➮ Network**, select your Ethernet connection, and click on **Advanced**.

Here, under **Proxies**, set up your proxies.

[image: Setup window]

All explained here: [Mac OS X 10.6 Help: Using Ethernet to connect to a network or the Internet](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.6/en/11939.html)